# Applying a specific TSLint rule from a regular TS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, tslint

I am trying to obtain filenames that have cyclomatic complexity higher than 4 and display them on the console. I was thinking of using the TSLint cyclomatic complexity rule for it.

I wrote a script in package.json that runs my newly created TS file. For example:

```
"scripts" {
    "cyclomatic-complexity": "node cyclomatic-complexity.ts"
}
```

In my TS file I wish to use the TSLint cyclomatic complexity rule and store the response in a variable and then log the response. So how can I use and execute a TSLint rule within a TS file?

**My aim here is to write a script that takes in an optional foldername that will be captured in my TS file (this part is done). Then I would be running the cyclomatic-complexity rule on that specific folder and log the results of files that fail the TSLint cyclomatic complexity rule. How can I achieve this? Or please suggest other optimal ways to achieve this.**